# Directory size as reported by stat on NTFS

Tags: directory, ntfs, size

We all have seen gazillions of directory size reports from ls or stat.  We know they don't mean real size of the content, but they do have meaning, but since the meaning is not very useful for normal situations, we learned to ignore them.  (And it's so often 4,0K that it's actually easy to learn to ignore them *visually*.)

Now I just `ll` a directory on my NTFS volume and I see:

- couple of "4,0K" folders
- a just-created folder with a bunch of Unicode-named files, showing "664
- on old folder showing zero, while still having subdirectories

So I wonder:  How directory size works with Linux and ntfs-3g?  How does stat or kernel count it?  How do records added to the directory influence this number?